# Translating strings from phtml file loaded in a trans emails in Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, transactional-mail, email-translation

I am loading some content from a phtml file, like:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='mynamespace_mymodule/adyen_reminder_items.phtml' subscriptionId=$subscriptionId orderId=$orderId}}
```

and in the adyen_reminder_items.phtml file I have strings like:
`<?php echo $this->__("Items in your order");?>` or `<?php echo $this->__("Price");?>`

I created a file `Mynamespace_Mymodule.csv` in the `app/locale/de_DE/` folder and in the config.xml I added:

```
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <files>
                    <default>Mynamespace_Mymodule.csv</default>
                </files>
            </fmynamespace_mymodule>
        </modules>
    </translate>
```

But when I am sending my email, I still go the english version instead of the german. Am I doing smth wrong ? What else should I try ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am sending email via cronjobs I am using a store emulation:

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(STORE ID HERE);
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale(Mage::app()->getStore(STORE ID HERE)->getCode())->init('frontend', true);
//do your magic here
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($emulation);
```

For some reason my locale wasn't set, so I set it manually, now my translation from locale/de_DE/Mynamespace_Mymodule.csv is recognized .

Hope this will help someone.

Cheers